# How can I make sure the content of a tkinter entry is saved on FocusOut?

Tags: python, tkinter, focusout, tkinter-entry

I have an app that uses `<FocusOut>` binding to automatically save the edits in an `Entry` to a list.

There is no problem saving the `Entry` text when using `TAB` to navigate through the Entries or when I click on another Entry, but If I change the text on one Entry and then if I mouse-click on a `ListBox` in another frame, `<FocusOut>` doesn't work on the last selected Entry and the information in it is not registered.

How can I avoid this without resorting to a `Save` button on the GUI? For every selection in the `ListBox` there are different `Entry` boxes, so the user would have to press the `Save` button numerous times. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Assuming that the listbox takes focus (which might not be true in all cases), then `<FocusOut>` will work as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Realtime edit / save text instead

It looks like you want to get the updated text realtime. What I do in such a case is use the `'KeyRelease'` -binding. Simple, effective enrtry- specific and works instantly.

In concept:

```py
win = Tk()
def dosomething(*args):
    # update the corresponding text anywhere, save your text, whatever
    print(entry.get())
    
entry = Entry()
entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", dosomething)
entry.pack()
    
win.mainloop()
```

[image]

In action:

```
M
Mo
Mon
Monk
Monke
Monkey
Monkey 
Monkey e
Monkey ea
Monkey eat
Monkey eats
Monkey eats 
Monkey eats b
Monkey eats ban
Monkey eats ban
Monkey eats bana
Monkey eats banan
Monkey eats banana
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!